# I want to store values in an arrayList of my own type from an array in java. How do I do so

Tags: java, arraylist

My problem:

```
al.get(i).setName()=arr[i];
```

This is being said as invalid as left-hand side should contain only an assignment.
So how can I store values ?

Comment: @SyedaZunairah The OP did.

Answer (score 6):

try

```
al.get(i).setName(arr[i]);
```

if you look at your code, you will probably see that the `setName` method takes a parameter.  I assume that the `arr` contains the same type of parameter.

Comment: Does this answer your question?  if so please consider to accept my answer.

Comment: There is another problem . I am getting an exception when i use al.get(i)

Answer (score 0):

The method name `setName()` implies that this method accepts a name as an argument (this is the convention for setter methods). Therefore, you should call this method with :

```
al.get(i).setName(arr[i]);
```

I noticed your comment about getting an exception when you use `al.get(i)`. There are two exceptions this expression may throw. If `al` is not initialized, you'll get a `NullPointerException`. The way to fix that is to initialize al with `al = new ArrayList<>();`. If you are attempting to access an invalid index (i.e. `i >= al.size()`), you'll get `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. In this case you should make sure that `i < al.size()` before calling `al.get(i)`.